# How to send the jquery array value to codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I am passing an array through jQuery like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/autocomplete/test_search?added_ids[]="+ids,

.....
```

Here is the network text from chrome

..../autocomplete/test_search?added_ids[]=5190,3574,5369&term=s

I have to catch this array in my controller to run a query like

```
$selected = $this->input->get('added_ids');

$this->db->select('first_nm, last_nm , title');
$this->db->where_not_in('my_id', $selected);
```

But for the first entry in the array it is working. The next element are not being excluded in the **where_not_in** section. Can you please help me where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Pass it as a string & than convert the values into an array using implode or join function.

Comment: send as `added_ids="+ids`

Answer (score 1):

use -

```
ids.join(", ");
```

and pass them as a string

Answer (score 1):

In your Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/autocomplete/test_search?added_ids="+ids.join("_"),
```

In controller

```
$selected = $this->input->get('added_ids');
$selected=explode('_',$selected);

$this->db->select('first_nm, last_nm , title');
$this->db->where_not_in('my_id', $selected);
```

You can use `.join()` to combine array elements .In your controller you can get element by using `explode()`

Answer (score 0):

Try
 `where_not_in()` function expects an array not a string.

```
$selected = $this->input->get('added_ids');
 $ids = explode(',',$selected[0]);
 $this->db->select('first_nm, last_nm , title');
 $this->db->where_not_in('my_id', $ids);
```

more info [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)